# Removing a usb camera from my Android device does not refresh the list

Tags: android, video, camera, usb, android-camera

I have this function that I call every 5 seconds:

```
     @NonNull
private ArrayList<LmiVideoCapturerDeviceInfo> getNumberOfCameras() {
    ArrayList<LmiVideoCapturerDeviceInfo> newDevices= new ArrayList<>();
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    Log.i("Refresh devices"," lookForDevicesChangesRunnable refresh devices size is!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!: " + numberOfCameras);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        Log.i("Refresh devices", "camera ids are: " + info.toString());
        String facing = "BACK";
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            facing = "FRONT";
        }
        newDevices.add(new LmiVideoCapturerDeviceInfo("Camera " + i, Integer.toString(i), "Camera" + i, facing));
    }
    return newDevices;
}
```

Now I for example at the beginning have 0 cameras, I add a camera in the usb plug, and it will update, and this will return 1, and it will refresh my list.

BUT If I have 1 camera connected, and I remove it, this function will still return 1, for a long time, even though the camera is not there anymore, and if I try to open it, in the app nothing happens, just get the last frame (from when  I removed it). Why isn't my list being updated sooner?
PS: the tv box set I'm using is Android 4.4.2 , so I cannot use Camera2 API, hence why I'm using the CameraAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in support for webcams in Android, so the manufacturer of your device must have added it.

Unfortunately, since there's no built-in support, it's fairly easy for there to be scenarios that don't work correctly. You're likely hitting one of those. You can try to report the problem to the manufacturer, but whether that'll get the issue resolved anytime soon is hard to say.

Comment: I understand that, but what I don't understand, is why getNumberOfCameras is not changing. I mean, I even try Camera.Open, it gets an exception, cause the camera is not found. So In my logic, wouldn't that set the camera as non existent, and refresh the "getNumberOfCameras" int?

Comment: In default AOSP code, the number of cameras is cached at boot and never changes.

So it sounds like the OEM has not added any code to handle the disconnect case to refresh the number, even though they handle the connect case (possibly by just restarting the camera service).